# Write on a Read Only NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc, readonly, overwrite

I'm new to android development. I'm creating an app that uses NFC, so I bought some Sony Xperia NFC tags. I'm trying to write a code to one of them but I'm getting a message that it is 'Read-Only'. Is there any chance to Write on it?

I know that maybe its a stupid question but I saw a video where it was possible to write to Sony Xperia smart tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try downloading a NFC App which is capable of writing to NFC tags from Google Play and see if the NFC tags work with the app. If not the NFC tag may be ReadOnly and you will have to buy new ones:

http://www.identivenfc.com/en/nfc-tags.htm
http://buynfcstickers.com/index.php/?mode=list
http://nfctags.tagstand.com/collections/nfc-kits/products/nfc-hobbyist-starter-kit-15-stickers
http://nfctags.tagstand.com/collections/nfc-kits/products/nfc-task-launcher-pack-6-tags

Comment: Thank you! Just ordered new ones. I was just trying to figure out if it's possible to clear the tag and re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

[NFC ReTag](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.widgapp.NFC_ReTAG_FREE&hl=en) claims that they can write to read-only tags:

> Works with ANY android supported tag = re-writable AND write
>   protected!

I have not personally tried the app.

Answer (score 0):

[NFC ReTag](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.widgapp.NFC_ReTAG_FREE&hl=en) doesn't really write on read-only tags. It just assign an ID number to each new tag that it recognises, and then every time you approach that tag it triggers the action you've selected.
I've tested it on Sony Xperia Smart Tags, which are read-only.